# Rubik's cube with twisted corner

Tags: rubiks-cube

So I was messing around with my newest Rubik's cube, and I apparently twisted a corner when solving it, and now I don't know what corner it was.

If there is someone out there that knows how to figure this out, that would be a great help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pictures of all sides of the cube's current state would help others identify the problem.

Comment: I guess, try your best to solve the Rubik first. At the end, there may be one corner which is twisted, twist that corner. Anyway as far as I know, twisting corner A doesn't imply you must twist corner A again to make the Rubik solvable (it can be solvable by twisting other corner, say corner B).

Answer (score 6):

It won't matter.

Using regular moves only, you can twist any two corners pairwise, one clockwise, the other anticlockwise, so you can move the misalignment to any corner piece you want.

The only thing that matters is that when you forcibly twist the misaligned corner back, you must do it in the opposite direction from the initial, accidentally forced twist: otherwise you end up in the other unsolvable alignment. (If you forcibly twist a single corner piece on a solved cube, that corner piece has three possible orientations, and only one of those results in a solvable cube.)

Solving the rest of the (corners of the) cube will tell you which direction is the correct one, which is why @athin recommends it in the comments.