# ASolver Rubik’s Cube Misunderstood Side Orientation

Tags: rubiks-cube

I bought a speed cube from a kid at my high school, and I tried using ASolver (to impress them of-course) and I got an error saying “wrong orientation of corner element”. I don’t know how to fix this, and I want to know if there is a trick to it. I would have to spend looking at 8 corner elements, including 3 different combinations each. Which is me putting in 24 different cube combinations into ASolver. I’m too lazy for that. Help :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rubik's cube with twisted corner](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59354/rubiks-cube-with-twisted-corner) (i.e. - it doesn't matter which corner you twist, just do one way and then the other)

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing the details of the cube or the app, I'd say there are two main possibilities:

1. a single corner piece was forcibly twisted into one of the two unsolvable configurations. (This is pretty common, and often happens by accident on loose speed cubes.)

To determine if this is the case, first solve any 7 corner pieces, and then fix by forcibly twisting the remaining piece into the correct orientation.

2. Some stickers have been swapped.

To determine if this is the case, one at a time, move each corner piece to its correct place and orientation. (The correct place and orientation can be determined by the centre pieces of the sides: those cannot be moved wrt. each other.) If you find a corner piece for which there is no place where you can match all three centre colours perfectly, then this is the case.

There's a common (may happen accidentally if you drop the cube so that some centre caps pop out) special case that's easy to fix:

- if you can match all the three colours but not the order of the colours, and this happens on every corner piece, then you have a mirrored centre block. Fix by choosing a pair of opposing sides, then pry off the cap on the centre piece on those sides, and swap them.

Otherwise, you'll probably need to take the cube apart, solve it piecewise as far as you can, and then try to find the minimum number of stickers you need to swap in order to make a solvable cube.

(To take a cube apart, rotate the top layer 45 degrees, and pop the middle piece of an edge out by pushing a flat head screw driver or something similar under it. The rest of the pieces should come apart easily after that.)

For more detailed instructions, please solve the cube as far as you are able to, and then post photos showing all the sides.